# Nested date_add in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

Instead of current_date I would like to use the date 30 days before current date.

```
created > date_add('month',-3,current_date)
```

See example below:

```
created > date_add('month',-3,current_date --> in this case 11th November) #take all the dates 3 month before 11th Nov.
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
created > date_add('month',-3,date_add('day',-30,current_date))
```

Comment: So [what](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) doesn't work? you got an error? what data type is created? Or it works, but it returns 4 months when you expected 3?

Comment: it works but it shows me as min(created) the 11th Nov and max(created) the 10th Dec instead of: 11th Aug and 11th Nov

Comment: So you're looking for something like : `where (created between date_add('month',-4,current_date) and date_add('month',-1,current_date))`. Maybe check what the min(created) is without where clause.

Comment: perfect that worked, thanks!